# AngularJS = scope in an = scope causing parse syntax error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to implement a  2 level hierarchy using directives in Angular. The first scope `venture` gets passed an JSON array of ventures. In every venture there is an array of positions. The second scope ideally pick up this position object and fill it in.

```
    app.directive('venture',function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<div><div ng-show="!ventureshow">{{details.venture_name}}'
                +'<positions data="{{details.positions}}" ></positions>'
                +'...',
        scope: {
            details:'='
        },
        replace: true,
        link:function($scope, element, attrs){
        }

    }
});

app.directive('positions',function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template:'d<ul ng-repeat="position in details">{{position}}<li>{{position.position_name}}:{{position.position_description}}</li></ul>',
        scope:{
            data:'='
        }
    }

})
```

However the equal (=) symbol on the second object causes an error `$parse:syntax`. Can't seem to figure out what's causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two way binding needs binding on a property which can be assigned to. You are instead providing an interpolated value by doing `data="{{details.positions}}"` which cannot be assigned to (unless you have a property on the scope with the same as that of the result of interpolation). You must be getting an un-assignable exception. Remove `{{` interpolations from binding when you do two way binding.

i.e

```
template: '<div><div ng-show="!ventureshow">{{details.venture_name}}'
            +'<positions data="details.positions" ></positions>'
```

Comment: Thanks you just gave me a better understanding of what I was doing

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse if you use 2 ways binding way (=),you must pass him variable,not the value of variable,beceause andgular directive needs a variable(place) to change something,to write something on.